# Charging battery animation over time

Tags: python

I have the following method that is working perfectly. Main problem I see is that I think it can be done just in one line, but I don't know how:

```
def _animate_display(self, display):
    self._timer += 1 / bge.logic.getAverageFrameRate()

    symbolic_level = self.battery.get_symbolic_level()

    if self._timer >= 5.0:
        self._timer = symbolic_level / 25
    elif (self._timer >= 4.0) and (symbolic_level <= 100):
        utils.change_texture(display, 'DisplayMat', 'icons/battery_100.png')
    elif (self._timer >= 3.0) and (symbolic_level <= 75):
        utils.change_texture(display, 'DisplayMat', 'icons/battery_75.png')
    elif (self._timer >= 2.0) and (symbolic_level <= 50):
        utils.change_texture(display, 'DisplayMat', 'icons/battery_50.png')
    elif (self._timer >= 1.0) and (symbolic_level <= 25):
        utils.change_texture(display, 'DisplayMat', 'icons/battery_25.png')
    elif (self._timer >= 0.0) and (symbolic_level <= 0):
        utils.change_texture(display, 'DisplayMat', 'icons/battery_0.png')
```

It models a simple animation of a charging battery in steps of 1 second. Something like: [....] --1s--> [=...] --1s--> [==..] --1s--> [===.] --1s--> [====] --1s--> [....] ...

Symbolic level is a variable that keep a value of [0, 25, 50, 75, 100], one of these, so animation loops from that symbolic value so it doesn't start from 0.

Comment: It's Python, so the chance it can be done on one line is quite high. However, is your focus on short or on readable? In both cases the repetition can be lessened, but it's all about intentions.

Comment: @Mast I think the shorter version would be still readable. I just don't find the relationship between the timer condition and the symbolic battery level.

Answer (score 2):

I took it to 6 to make it a little more readable:

```
def _animate_display(self, display):
    self._timer += 1 / bge.logic.getAverageFrameRate()
    symbolic_level = self.battery.get_symbolic_level()
    if self._timer >= 5.0:
        self._timer = symbolic_level / 25
    else:
        utils.change_texture(display, 'DisplayMat', 'icons/battery_{}.png'.format(next((x,y) for x,y in zip(xrange(100, -1, -25), xrange(4, -1, -1)) if symbolic_level <= x and self._timer >= y)))
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not working even after changing the level and timer variables by symbolic_level and self._timer :/ Moreover it seems like black magic for me; I guess my way isn't so bad at all :P

Comment: @Puyover: I would agree that your way isn't bad, but what doesn't work for mine?

Comment: no errors are displayed but animation is not working. Since it's Python 3 I have replaced xrange with range. Maybe there is the problem...

Comment: Using `range()` instead of `xrange()` shouldn't make a difference.  I don't know why it doesn't work.  I tested it on my end.